# "IDE internal Error Occurred" in Android

Tags: android, ide

```
Outdated stub in index: jar://C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/gradle/3.1.1/d0752c46bc1c728ce5294c31838fe5ae4bd36f2f/gradle-3.1.1-sources.jar!/com/android/build/gradle/TestedExtension.java null, doc=null, docSaved=true, wasIndexedAlready=true, queried at 1523337067209
indexed lengths={chars=242, bytes=252}
doc length=-1
file length=7618
```

IDE internal Error Occurred

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: I have the same error began to appear every time. try to do "menu File -> Invalidate / Restart"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an "internal error" and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357557/what-is-an-internal-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)